# Intel HD Graphics 3000 Opengl 3.2

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been trying to use some features of OGL 3.2 (Geometry shaders and other things) but the framework I was using returned an error which was triggered here:

```
if(major == 3 && minor < 2) {   //Graphics hardware does not support ENOUGH of OGL 3! Erk...
    std::cout << "OGLRenderer::OGLRenderer(): Device does not support OpenGL 3.2!" << std::endl;
    wglDeleteContext(tempContext);
    return;
}
```

After investigating, I found that my Laptop has the latest Intel HD Graphics 3000 drivers but it only supports up to OGL 3.1. I was doing this on Visual C++ 2010 Express and Windows 8.1.

Is there any way I can get support for higher versions? or will I need to switch to another machine?

Comment: Sometimes, even though the driver doesn't fully support the version you want, some of it's features might still be available through extensions. If not then you are out of luck until they update their drivers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your OpenGL version is hardware dependent. If you cannot create an OpenGL 3.2 context, and your drivers are up to date, then you will need to use hardware that supports OpenGL 3.2

Alternatively if you cannot upgrade your hardware you can use OpenGL ARB extensions that may be available on your hardware that are actually core in OpenGL 3.2

So technically you maybe be able to use OpenGL 3.2 features even if your hardware does not support it. Until OSX Mavericks I was stuck on OpenGL 3.2 and I wanted to use OpenGL 3.3 features, so I just used ARB extensions until then, and they worked great.

Answer (score 0):

[Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/) 10.0 [supports OpenGL 3.3](http://www.mesa3d.org/relnotes/10.0.html).  In software.